# Custom View with UITableView and UIButton, Button Interaction is working but UITableView is not interactable, it doesn't scroll or didSelect is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would really like some insight on this.

I have MainViewController which has .Xib file that has UITableView and UIButton on top of UIView. UIButton TouchUpInside is called but tableview is not scrollable or touchable. I have implemented delegate and datasource as well as succesfully loading the customview.

Here is the code:

## import "MainViewController.h"

```
@interface MainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arr ;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *myCustomView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mainTable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aboutButton;
@end
```

@implementation MainViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainViewController" owner:self options:0];
    _myCustomView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    _myCustomView.frame=self.view.bounds; // make view fill screen - customize as necessary
    
    [self.view addSubview:_myCustomView];
    self.mainTable.delegate = self;
    self.mainTable.dataSource = self;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Ball",@"Cat", nil];
    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)aboutButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"About button touched");
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _arr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Touched at index %li", (long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: [self.myCustomView bringSubviewToFront: mainTable]; add this line in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks @Chandan it worked.